# Pixel manipulation by python matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pixel

I found the python matplotlib function very useful. I would be much better for image processing if each individual pixel is fixed.

I would like to do pixel by pixel processing. The problem is, after using the "handles.append" function, the image margin changes.

```
from skimage.io import imread

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = imread('uk_figure.png')

my_dpi = 96
plt.figure(figsize=(800/my_dpi, 800/my_dpi), dpi = my_dpi, frameon=False)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig1.set_figheight(40)  #image size is set here, pixel = 8 *100 = 800
fig1.set_figwidth(40)   #image size is set here, pixel = 8 *100 = 800

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

#to add code below

plt.axis("off")
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right =1, top =1, bottom =0)
plt.savefig("uk_figure_addcolor4.png", pad_inches=0)
```

The figure saved is EXACTLY the same as original image. Thus, I think I could process the two image by pixel by pixel processing.

After added this code, matplotlib automatically added a margin for my image. Thus, pixel by pixel processing fails. Is there a way to instruct matplotlib to save image with fixed pixel?

```
x = [457,458,459,460]
y = [288,289,290,291]
handles = []
handles.append(plt.scatter(x,y, color='blue', marker='+')) #margin changes after adding this line
```

Answer (score 1):

The margin is added due to a change in the axis-limits.  If your image is 1000 by 1000 pixels big say, you can solve your problem by adding `plt.gca().set_xlim(0, 1000)` and `plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1000)`.  `plt.gca()` will get you the current axis, and then to that axis set the x- and y-limits.

Note: You might need to invert the y-limits to `plt.gca().set_ylim(1000, 0)`, since matplotlib usually chooses the upper left corner as the origin for images.  I used random data so its hard to tell if the image is flipped or not, but if you have a motive in your image you can very easy tell if the image is flipped or not.   If it is flipped, invert the ylim as above.